# unresolved dependencies while building spark 1.6.2

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

As the [spark documents](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/building-spark.html#building-a-runnable-distribution) says, I run `./build/sbt -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver assembly` to build spark 1.6.2, but there is an error like:

> [info] Updating
>   {file:/home/charlielin/workspace/spark-1.6.2/}network-shuffle...
>   [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ... [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.6.2: configuration not
>   public in org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.6.2: 'test'. It
>   was required from org.apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle_2.10;1.6.2
>   test [warn]   :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn] 
>   [warn]    Note: Unresolved dependencies path: [warn]
>         org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.10:1.6.2
>   ((com.typesafe.sbt.pom.MavenHelper) MavenHelper.scala#L76) [warn]
>   +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.10:1.6.2 sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.6.2: configuration not
>   public in org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.6.2: 'test'. It
>   was required from org.apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle_2.10;1.6.2
>   test

Is there any hint?

Comment: It looks like an internet connection issue. As dependencies are not downloaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this question by deleting `~/.ivy2` path.